# iOS: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification called multiple times on certain devices

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmediaplayercontroller

I have an application that plays back music.

I'm using the following code to listen to playback state changes from the MPMusicPlayerController to update the UI. More precisely I toggle the look of the play button between play and pause.

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[notificationCenter addObserver: self
                       selector: @selector (handle_NowPlayingItemChanged:)
                           name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                         object: self.musicPlayer];

[notificationCenter addObserver: self
                       selector: @selector (handle_PlaybackStateChanged:)
                           name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                         object: self.musicPlayer];

[self.musicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```

This works great on an **iPod Touch (iOS 5)** and **iPhone 3GS (iOS 5)**. Every time the playback state changes I get the following callback:

```
[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 1
```

where 1 means `MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying`.

However if I run the same on a **iPad 1 (iOS 5)**, **iPad 2 (iOS 5)** or **iPad 3 (iOS 6)** I get the following sequence instead of just one single callback:

```
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 1
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 2
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 1
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 2
```

where 2 means `MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused` and causes my application to display the wrong state in the UI, because the song is actually being played back.

The funny thing is, that once in a while the sequence is

```
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 1
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 2
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 1
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 2
-[JBMediaPlayer handle_PlaybackStateChanged:] :: playbackState: 1
```

which ends up correctly with 1 `MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying`, however still doesn't make sense that the callback gets called 5 times, with alternating values.

Any ideas on how to solve this or suggestion what else I can test to narrow down the problem?

---

Since I haven't received an answer here so far, I also cross-posted the question to the **Apple Developer Forum**: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/158426

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same bug reported here:

[Getting wrong playback state in MP Music Player Controller in ios 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118726/getting-wrong-playback-state-in-mp-music-player-controller-in-ios-5)

I posted a workaround for the bug in that question.

Comment: And what should I do with this information? How can I get the correct state? Or how can I reset the player?

Answer (score 0):

You can check real playback state using currentPlaybackRate property. MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused must match rate 0.0. An example how can it implemented is shown below...

```
- (void)musicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    float playbackRate = [((MPMusicPlayerController *)notification.object) currentPlaybackRate];
    MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = (MPMusicPlaybackState)[notification.userInfo[@"MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateKey"] integerValue];
    switch (playbackState) {
        case MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused:
            if (playbackRate <= .0f) {
                self.playbackState = playbackState;
            }
            break;
        default:
            self.playbackState = playbackState;
            break;
    }
}
```

Thus it is possible to cut off false pause notification.